# How to get the value of a promise with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, callback, fetch-api

I am currently working on an assignment where we are fetching a word from an API for a hangman game. The following method was provided and cannot be altered:

```
getRandomWord(difficulty) {
return fetch(
`https://it3049c-hangman.fly.dev?difficulty=${difficulty}`
)
.then((r) =\> r.json())
.then((r) =\> r.word);
}
```

```
getRandomWord is called from this method: 

  start(difficulty, next) {
    this.word = this.getRandomWord(difficulty).then();
    this.clearCanvas();
    this.drawBase();
    this.guesses = "";
    this.isOver = false;
    this.didWin = false;
  }
```

where the 'next' parameter is passed in as a callback function from this event listener:

```
  difficultySelectForm.addEventListener(`submit`, function (event) {

    let userDifficulty = difficultySelect.value;

   
    const next = () => {

      
      startWrapper.classList.add("hidden");
      gameWrapper.classList.remove("hidden");
      wordHolderText.innerText = game.getWordHolderText();
      guessesText.innerText = game.getGuessesText();

       
      return;
    };
    game.start(userDifficulty, next);

  });
```

my issue is that the callback function uses the return value of getRandomWord, but getRandomWord is only ever returning a promise and I can not figure out how to resolve that before kicking it to the callback function.

I have tried:

this.word = this.getRandomWord(difficulty).then(next);

expecting the promise to be fulfilled and the next function to execute but it does not execute.

Comment: `this.getRandomWord(difficulty).then(function(word) { /* your code here */ });`